Why Does My Android Studio App Keep Crashing to a Black Screen?
I've been working on an Android app using Android Studio, but I keep encountering this frustrating problem. Whenever I launch the app on my device or emulator, instead of seeing the expected interface, all I get is a black screen. I'm not sure what's causing this issue or how to fix it. But, I suspect it might be related to my equipment. My PC has 16GB of RAM and my processor is an AMD A-8 7680 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C + 6G. Can you help me understand why my app is crashing to a black screen and what steps I can take to resolve it?

I attempted to resolve the issue by upgrading the API level to 34, but unfortunately, the problem persists. I was hoping that updating the API level would address the black screen crashing issue, but it seems that wasn't the solution.

Have you checked the logcat for errors? If you are seeing a black screen, your app did not crash, you have a layout issue. Also, we would need to see some code and your layout files to help you more.

Removed android-studio tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

my logcat was 'No connected devices'  plus theres no choice , it was a blank only .

but sir @DavidWasser , there was no problem in my specs? it was a normal ?

Have you taken screenshot of the screenshot? That makes it look a little like you're running android studio in a VM - if you are that could certainly explain it. Either way, changing the hardware emulation settings for the simulator might get you somewhere: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

@Mr.Kraken Does the simulator show the android home screen before you start the app? Or as soon as it opens does it look like it does in the screenshot?

I thought you said you also have this problem on an actual device? If so, this isn't a simulator/VM problem

You have to have a simulator or device  connected to see the Logcat

@DavidWasser i dont have a phone but the expectation of result is while im running the play button or the run button , the emulator pops up but i saw the logcat does not connected devices and it shows the 3 sec display the crash app..
